# Which encoding does the built in CSV parser in Python 3 support?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I need to know which encoding it support but it's not in the documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Here are the format I want to support:

```
ANSI
UTF-8
UNICODE
win1251
UTF-16LE
```

I there like a inclusive list that I can use to build my UI on?

EDIT: My files are on a external FTP server uploaded by user so they will not use my system default encoding.  They can be in any format.  I need to tell the user what encoding I support.

Answer (score 0):

`csv` is not encoding-aware. Use `open()` for that.

From the [docs you linked](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

> Since [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is used to open a CSV file for reading, the file will by default be decoded into unicode using the system default encoding (see [`locale.getpreferredencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding)). To decode a file using a different encoding, use the `encoding` argument of open:
>
> ```
> import csv
> with open('some.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
>     reader = csv.reader(f)
>     for row in reader:
>         print(row)
> ```
>
> The same applies to writing in something other than the system default encoding: specify the encoding argument when opening the output file.

For which encodings are supported, see [the docs for `open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> *encoding* is the name of the encoding used to decode or encode the file. This should only be used in text mode. The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever [`locale.getpreferredencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) returns), but any [text encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-text-encoding) supported by Python can be used. See the [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#module-codecs) module for the list of supported encodings.

Comment: My files are on a FTP server so the encoding are not using system default.   The open command have the option to give it an encoding to use and this is the part I am concerned about.

Comment: @Bill What do you mean? Are you asking how to check a filesystem's default encoding?

Comment: I retrieve the files on an external FTP server so I can't garrantee what format they will be in.  They could be in any format.  What I plan to do is to build a UI to have the user just tell me which format their file is in, so when I parse it I can tell python which format the file is in.  In order to do this I need to present the user with a list of encoding that I support, which is why I ask what format does the python csv parser support so I can correctly tell the user.

Comment: @Bill What do you mean by "format"? If you mean *encoding*, that's already covered in the answer. Check `codecs` for the full list.

Comment: Yes I mean encoding.  OK I will check that out.

Comment: The list of codecs does not include Unicode.  I am guessing it's because Unicode is a class of encoding.

Comment: @Bill Yes, Unicode is a class of encodings including UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, etc. I think UCS-2 was historically called "Unicode", but then it was renamed, then expanded to become UTF-16.

Comment: That's supremely confusing.